# Inbound properties are lost in transition between two flows

Tags: properties, mule, inbound, mule-flow

There are two flows Flow1, Flow2.
In Flow1 i am able to get some inbound properties and i copy these properties to outbound scope.

```
println 'Copying inbound properties to session:'
message.inboundPropertyNames.each { prop ->
    message.setOutboundProperty(prop, message.getInboundProperty(prop))
    println 'Setting ' + prop + ' --> ' + message.getInboundProperty(prop)
}
```

But i am not able to get these outbound properties in Flow2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling flow 2 via an outbound-endpoint, the properties you put in the outbound scope will be moved back to the inbound scope. So you will need to access them as inboundProperties in flow 2.

Also, you could also use the copy-properties transformer to handle the copying for you:

`<copy-properties propertyName="•" />`

Comment: That's right. Inbound properties are set by the inbound endpoint when a message arrives, and outbound properties are used by the outbound endpoint to send them when the message leaves the flow. If the message leaves Flow1 with some outbound properties, and then reach Flow2, the inbound endpoint in the later will provide the properties as inbound properties. Regards, Marcos.